# How to check if listed Wi-Fi signal is secured?

Tags: android, wifi

Can I check if a boradcasting SSID is secured with a key, without attempting to connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)'s `getScanResults` method, and check [ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities)'s capabilities field value.

```
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wm.startScan();

    //some time after...

    List<ScanResult> results = wm.getScanResults();
    for( ScanResult result : results ){
        //if this ap is locked, the capabilities string should contains..
        //the name of encryption mechanism. ex> [WPA2-EAP-CCMP]
        Log.v("AP", "AP:" + result.capabilities);
    }
```

In my case, the result log looks like this...

```
09-16 21:01:41.308  V/AP﹕ AP:[WPA-EAP-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-EAP-CCMP+TKIP][ESS]
09-16 21:01:41.308  V/AP﹕ AP:[WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]
09-16 21:01:41.308  V/AP﹕ AP:[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]
09-16 21:01:41.308  V/AP﹕ AP:[WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]
09-16 21:01:41.308  V/AP﹕ AP:[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]
09-16 21:01:41.308  V/AP﹕ AP:[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]
```

You may need below permissions in order to scan & read result.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```